# PostgreSQL pass table name and column name as arguments to function

Tags: postgresql

I have two almost similar tables: `posts` and `comments`.

Both of them has column `id` and `votes`.

Also i have two tables `posts_votes` and `comments_votes` that also has an almost similar structure: both of them has column `value` (can be `-1` or `+1`), has user_id as `FOREIGN KEY` to `user_account` table, and field `post_id` or `comment_id` depending on which table it is, for `posts_votes` it will be `post_id`, and for `comments_votes` it will be `comment_id`.

What i need, is to write a trigger that will update `votes` counter for `posts` and `comments` table each time the row inserted/deleted/updated in `posts_votes` or `comments_votes` table.

It can be easily done by writing to different triggers, with difference only in table name for update query, and column name for `WHERE` statement.

This is example of such trigger for posts table (full DDL [here](https://pastebin.com/VrckcXHj)):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_votes_counter() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
  BEGIN;
    IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
      UPDATE posts SET votes = votes + NEW.value WHERE id = NEW.post_id;
    ELSIF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
      UPDATE posts SET votes = votes - OLD.value WHERE id = OLD.post_id;
    ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
      UPDATE posts SET votes = votes - OLD.value + NEW.VALUE WHERE id = NEW.post_id;
    END IF;
  END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

What i want, is to **write single function with arguments as table name and column with reference, so i can use this function in both cases for two tables**.

It will be like this:

```
update_votes_counter('posts', 'post_id');
update_votes_counter('comments', 'comment_id');
```

and the function should build query like this:

`UPDATE $table_name$ SET votes = votes + NEW.value WHERE id = NEW.$column_name$`

Thanks for any advices!

Comment: I suggest you to evaluate the use a table for both post_and_comments with a field 'type' that can has the value 'post' or 'comment'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo can create the functions dynamicaly to get a pair of static triggers doing this:

```
DO
$COMMAND$
declare
  v_sql text:=
$CREATES$
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_votes_in_posts() RETURNS TRIGGER AS 
$$
  BEGIN
    IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
      UPDATE posts SET votes = votes + NEW.value WHERE id = NEW.post_id;
    ELSIF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
      UPDATE posts SET votes = votes - OLD.value WHERE id = OLD.post_id;
      return old;
    ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
      UPDATE posts SET votes = votes - OLD.value + NEW.value WHERE id = NEW.post_id;
    END IF;
    return new;
  END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER update_votes_in_posts 
  AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON posts_votes
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_votes_in_posts();
$CREATES$;
begin
  execute v_sql;
  execute replace(v_sql, 'post', 'comment');
end;
$COMMAND$;
```

In one command (the DO) you set a variable (v_sql) that it contains the trigger for the posts table. You can execute the content of that variable directly. Then you can replace the inside the variable content all ocurrences of post (replacing with comment).

¡Voilá!

Look at a running complete example of this in: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=f6c9931bc985f3ee7ebec7ee51c5017f

Answer (score 0):

As one guy in Telegram messenger said to me, it can be done also in this way:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_votes_counter() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
  $$
  DECLARE
    entity_id INT;
    value SMALLINT;
  BEGIN
    IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT' OR TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN 
        EXECUTE format('SELECT ($1).%I', TG_ARGV[1]) INTO entity_id USING NEW;
    ELSE
        EXECUTE format('SELECT ($1).%I', TG_ARGV[1]) INTO entity_id USING OLD;
    END IF;

    IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
      value = NEW.value;
    ELSIF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
      value = -OLD.value;
    ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
      IF (OLD.value = NEW.value) THEN
        RETURN NEW;
      END IF;

      value = -OLD.value + NEW.value;
    end if;

    EXECUTE format('UPDATE %I SET votes = votes + $1 WHERE id = $2', TG_ARGV[0]) USING value, entity_id;

    RETURN NEW;
  end;
  $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER posts_votes_updates AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON posts_votes FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_votes_counter('posts', 'post_id');
```